# What would you call someone that is very enthusiastic about something silly or trivial?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What would you call someone
who is very enthusiastic about something silly or trivial? 
For example, one who is exceedingly enthusiastic about some bad singer or band, without knowing that there are much better ones around and does not realise (or does not care) that his exaggerated appreciation is the subject of ridicule.

Comment: There are lots of words for an extreme/excessive fan, e.g. fanboy/fangirl, stan, nerd, geek, fanatic. None really has your full meaning (ignorance of better things) but many suggest ridicule.

Comment: Do you want a pejorative term (a value judgement)? Some people like simple pleasures, and might not share your taste in music.

Comment: "Bad singer" is an interesting example: There are some internationally successful bands with singers who cannot seem to sing in tune - something that can be objectively measured, and that non-fans find subjectively annoying, yet it apparently doesn't bother their many fans.

Answer (score 1):

In British slang they might be called an [Anorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anorak_(slang)).

> "Anorak" /ˈænəræk/ is a British slang term which refers to a person who has a very strong interest, perhaps obsessive, in niche subjects. This interest may be unacknowledged or not understood by the general public.
> ...
> **Etymology**
> The first use of the phrase to describe an obsessive fan has been credited to the radio presenter Andy Archer, who used the term in the early 1970s for fans of offshore radio, who would charter boats to come out to sea to visit the radio ships.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anorak_(slang))
>
> In 1983, the first edition of the Anoraks UK Weekly Report was published, featuring news of pirate radio broadcasts.[2]
>
> In 1984 the Observer newspaper used the term as a metonym for the prototype group interested in detailed trivia, the trainspotters,[3][4] as members of this group often wore unfashionable but warm parkas called "anoraks" when standing for hours on station platforms or along railway tracks, noting down details of passing trains.

Comment: This might mark me as an "anorak" but I'd like to point out that an _anorak_ and a _parka_ are different garments. An anorak is much shorter coming down only to the hips while a parka comes down to the mid thighs. Parkas were worn by the "Mods" in the 1960s as protection from the elements when riding scooters (remember the film [Quadrophenia]( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrophenia_(film)) ) but most Mods would have thought anoraks terminally uncoool

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***dilettante**?*

> **[Oxford Dictionary on Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dilettante)**:
>
>   A person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts,
>   without real commitment or knowledge.
>   *‘a wealthy literary dilettante’*
>
> **[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dilettante)**:
>
> You can use **dilettante** to talk about someone
> who seems interested in a subject, especially in art,
> but who does not really know very much about it.
> [formal, disapproval]
> **[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dilettante)**:
>
> someone who is interested in something such as art or music
> but does not know very much about it

Unfortunately, it doesn't specifically embody the notion
of *excessive* enthusiasm or ridiculousness,
although the Collins entry suggests that it can be used as a pejorative.